# App runs well in Chrome but not in Android

Tags: android, flutter, web

I have developed a flutter app that runs well in Chrome (Web-based) but when I try to run on Android phone it gives me the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Will be grateful if someone can send me solution.

D:\flutterapps\etea>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1165], locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 2.2.3 at c:\flutter
• Framework revision f4abaa0735 (8 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
• Engine revision 241c87ad80
• Dart version 2.13.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Justinmind\Justinmind 9.2.0\app\jdk\9.2.0\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
• Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• SM A205F (mobile) • R58M739343L • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
• Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159
• Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.78

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor -v` to your post.

Comment: delete .gradle folder and rebuild again and yeah take a backup before doing that